# Best way to do simple new employee laptop setup for Windows 10/11 without Windows Server or cloning

Tags: windows-10, automation, windows-installation, deployment

I ran a few Windows based labs over a decade ago, past few years I've mostly been managing Macs and systems in AWS and GCP.  Right now the company is hiring a lot of finance folks who want to work on Windows laptops.  The basic setup is I setup a local admin account so we always can get back into the machine, add a user account for the new employee, and install basic apps like Google Chrome, Office, Zoom, etc. nothing too fancy.  We don't have Active Domain control running, don't have SCCM at this time.  With this context, I was wondering if there's a way to do a simple automated install to new laptops similar to MacOS Migration Assistant, where a new laptop already has a fresh Windows OS from the factory, and I just want to transfer the user account and additional apps installed.  I did some research and mostly saw more elaborate enterprise options using SCCM and Windows Server etc.

Comment: This may be a better question for https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Unless you want to get into Sysprep (need 15 or 20 machines at one time to make that worthwhile), make yourself an installation writeup for OEM machines that come with Windows. Making an Admin user and Business user is a really good idea.

Comment: @Bob thanks will post there